# Extract numbers from strings

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file containing on each line a string of the form

```
string1.string2:\string3{string4}{number}
```

and what I want to extract is the number. I've searched and tried for a while to get this done using sed or bash, but failed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit 1: The strings may contains numbers.

Comment: Yep, we certainly are...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ echo 'string1.string2:\string3{string4}{number}' |\
  cut -d'{' -f3 | cut -d'}' -f 1
number
```

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed 's/[^}]*}{\([0-9]*\)}/\1/' input_file
```

Description:

```
[^}]*}      : match anything that is not } and the following }
{\([0-9]*\)}: capture the following digits within {...}
/\1/        : substitute all with the captured number
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -o '\{[0-9]\+\}' | tr -d '[{}]'
```

Comment: What if a number is in one of the strings? In addition, `grep` selects *lines*, not *fields* in those lines.

Comment: Yes, the strings themselves may have numbers. I will edit the question to make this clear.

Comment: Fixed it. Only match numbers within curly braces, and post-remove them.

Answer (score 0):

In bash:

```
sRE='[[:alnum:]]+'
nRE='[[:digit:]]+'
[[ $str =~ $sRE\.$sRE:\\$sRE\{$sRE\}\{($nRE)\} ]] && number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

You can drop the first part of the regular expression, if your text file is sufficiently uniform:

```
[[ $str =~ \\$sRE{$sRE}{($nRE)} ]] && number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

or even

```
[[ $str =~ {$sRE}{($nRE)} ]] && number=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
```

Comment: I think `sRE` should be `[[:alnum:]]+`, and I need to escape the curly braces to make this work here.

Comment: Right on both counts. I wondered about the braces, but was too lazy to check.